# Polyfill for generators for ES5 with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generator

I'm trying to make generators and iterations working with TypeScript for ES5. I'm using the following compiler options.

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
     "DOM",
     "ES5",
     "ScriptHost",
     "es2015.iterable" // Fixes "Cannot find global type 'IterableIterator'."
   ],
"downlevelIteration": true // Fixes "Type 'IterableIterator<number> is not an array type or a string type."
```

In my test class I have:

```
public test = () => {
    for (const i of this.generator(1)) {
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }
}

*generator(count: number) {
    while (true)
        yield count++;
}
```

In newer browser this works but with older ones `undefined` is logged. The [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/release%20notes/TypeScript%202.3.md) say

> ...this requires a native Symbol.iterator or Symbol.iterator shim at runtime for any non-array values.

How do I get this?

Comment: Google tells me this should contain a working shim: https://github.com/medikoo/es6-symbol

Comment: @Marv Seems this requires a bundler unfortunately.

Comment: You can load polyfills without bundler from https://polyfill.io